# HTML5 and high resolution displays

Tags: html

I'm trying to handle the situation where my page is displayed on a 21:9 ultra-wide display in full-screen but when I'm trying to get the `window.innerWidth` or `document.body.clientWidth` I get an incorrect result.

Testing this particular display (which runs a resolution of 3440x1440) with

http://whatsmyscreenresolution.com/

returns the odd value of `Your screen resolution is 2293 x 960`

What could cause this?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a scaling factor of 1.5 somewhere in the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the reason this value shows up is that monitor has a DPI of 280.

A more refined technique that takes DPI into account, as employed by http://dpi.lv/ shows the correct  resolution.

It's better to handle this based on the aspect ratio, rather than pixel size anyway. 3440/1440 and 2293/960 are both ~2.38

Comment: I want to note that even that other site you mentioned doesn't show the correct resolution in my end. W10 with a 4K 15" screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some scaling going on here. I am on a 4K screen, but it shows an entirely different resolution than I actually have and use.

Using different browsers yield the same result. I guess Windows (or any other platform you use), automatically scales your entire system to keep those tiny letters readable. That is what you experience now.

Comment: on further digging http://dpi.lv/ shows the correct resolution so it's the PPI that throws me off.

Comment: That would be it then.

Comment: Oops. Windows is set here to 250% view... That would explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild uninformed guess!
Could it be that the 'logical pixel' size.
i.e. (size / DPI * 96) ?